# I am unable to run AppImage bundles on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, appimage

This is a recent issue. It worked previously.  I find that I cannot run any AppImage bundle on 22.04 LTS.  I confirmed that libfuse2 is installed.  But to ensure that is was installed correctly, I uninstalled and reinstalled it via apt-get.
When I attempt to execute the AppImage in Gnome, absolutely nothing happens and I get no error.  But when I attempt to execute it via the command line, I get:
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2
Has anyone else encountered and resolved this issue?

Comment: I thought I should add that the bundle I am attempting to run is Balena Etcher (balenaEtcher-1.7.8-x64.AppImage).  Also, I noted that in addition to fuse2, I have discovered that fuse3 is also installed on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution to the AppImage issue but more of a workaround.  I found that I could download the app (Balena Etcher) in .deb format.  I did that, installed it and it worked fine.  I still have no idea why the Etcher AppImage bundle is no longer running correctly.  I found that Ubuntu has both fuse2 and fuse 3 installed on the machine and running the AppImage bundle for Balena Etcher results in the error I described in the original question.